# Can I still drive my car when one of the tires has lower pressure?

Tags: pressure

I just noticed this morning that one of my tire pressure dropped a little bit. The others are 34psi, but the front right tire is only 30psi, I checked them only few days ago, they were the same at that time. This happened before and I think it will keep dropping.

My regular car maintainance has been scheduled on Saturday, can I still drive to work (~ 40miles daily) for three days?

Comment: Is the ~40mi round trip or one way?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Ideally you wouldn't want to drive too fast. If you have a front wheel drive or rear wheel drive, you could swop the tire with another so that it's not one of the driving wheels. This is to protect your differential from getting too hot and being damaged.

If you have a 4wd or 4x4, it's more important that all wheels are inflated equally and that their circumference are all close to the same.

All this being said, **a difference of 4psi isn't that severe**.

FYI: if you want to really cover all your bases, [get a mobile compressor like one of these (for example) to carry around in your trunk](http://www.aircompressorsdirect.com/tools/tire-inflators.html)

Comment: Thank you, I have 2012 Toyota Camry, I think it is front wheel drive. how much difference can be considered as severe?

Comment: I can't give you an exact figure. If the wheel is noticeably flat, I wouldn't drive far on it.